# The passwords have been used for the second or more time

Tags: american-english, ordinal-numbers

Is there any word/structure in English for the following usage?

> Here we calculate the total number of times that account passwords have been used for the second ***or more time (third, or higher number of times)***.

Is there any other way of putting this in English other than the following?

> Here we calculate the total number of times that account passwords have been used twice or more.

Comment: Writing advice is off-topic. FWIW: *The passwords have been used two or more times.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about writing advice.

Comment: Sorry folks, there's no writing advice being sought here that I see.

Comment: Is it necessary to use the number "two'? What's wrong with "The password has been reused"?

Comment: Your original is not even clear enough to know how to rewrite it.

Comment: Even with the edits, this is still unclear.  Allow me to try to interpret (if this is right, feel free to edit into your question).  There is an application with many users.  Some users have the same password as other users.  You are generating a report showing how often this happens.  You need a good way to document what the report shows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say:

> This password has been used twice or more

Or:

> This password has been used twice at least.

Comment: The commas are inappropriate.

Comment: "At least, this password has been used twice" - you're right

Comment: "*At least, this password has been used twice.*" means something completely different than "*This password has been used at least twice.*"

Comment: @michael.hor257k don't see what you mean. Can you explain it?

Comment: In a nutshell, the "at least" part refers to the entire part that follows it, not to the number of usages. The message that comes across is that the password has been used exactly twice - but that's the bright side of an otherwise bad situation.

Comment: Note also that OP is trying to describe a **group** of passwords that have been used twice or more (each) - not any individual password.

Comment: @michael.hor257k well...as far as I read it is not "exactly twice", it is twice or more. So I don't see any problem on what I just answered. Please note that "at least" doesn't change its meaning regardless of its position in the sentence. "I want three, at least" or "At least, I want three" or "I, at least, want three". It is a question of rhetoric.

Comment: "*Please note that "at least" doesn't change its meaning regardless of its position in the sentence.*" This is where we disagree.

Comment: I see, anyways do you have any thoughts? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comments, but could you kindly address the edited question?

Comment: I am a native (British) English speaker, and I must agree with @michael: "At least this password has been used twice", with or without the comma, is completely different from "This password has been used at least twice." It sounds a bit unusual, but I think its most likely meaning is "This password has been used twice, and perhaps other passwords have also been used twice." It's not a question of rhetoric; you are simply mistaken.

Comment: Which one is the correct then?

Comment: I wrote first "this password has been used, at least, twice". And Iater I changed it to omit the commas and now I see what you mean - putting at least at the beginning I am saying that this password has been used twice and maybe others too. I would say that this one is the one that differs on meaning from the other two possible options, "this password has been used twice at least" and "this password has been, at least, used twice" (this last one would be the unusual or the rhetorical one, even when some people dislike commas).

Comment: "This password has been used twice at least": yes, this is fine. "This password has been, at least, used twice": no, this is meaningless, with or without commas. It has to be "This password has been used at least twice." Without commas.

Comment: Thanks TonyK - commas are not welcome, got it, let's not give room to ambiguities